# What is the difference in meaning among these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

1. Walking is good exercise.
2. Walking is a good exercise.
3. Walking is a good form of exercise.

I'd like to know the difference in meaning among these sentences.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, there is a progressive **narrowing of focus** as to why **walking is beneficial** beginning generally and becoming more specific

> Walking is good exercise.
>   Walking is **generally a healthy thing to do**
>
> Walking is **a** good exercise.
>   Walking is **one of many different exercises** which may also be healthy.
>
> Walking is **a** good **form of** exercise.
>   It is **low impact and aerobic** as opposed to running which is **high impact**.